# iOS Detect aggressive behavior of a vehicle driver

Tags: ios, core-location, core-motion

I am working on a driver behavior app and I am using [SOMotionDetector](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMotionDetector) (Thanks to MIT). Its giving speed and Motion Type (Not Moving, Walking, Running, Automotive) of device. I will use Automotive in my case as I need to detect driver behavior. This is detecting  Motion Type based on speed with some thresholds set for Walking, Running, Automotive or if available it uses M7 Chip. It updates location approximately after every second (time varies based on GPS) in `[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].locationChangedBlock` To detect Aggressive speed or break I am checking is that the increase/decrease of speed in last second. If it increases from a certain threshold (I am using `kAggressiveSpeedIncrementFactor 8.0f`) then its aggressively increasing speed, and if there is decreasing speed (difference factor is negative in this case) then its aggressive break. For turn I am playing with angle of latitude and longitude points, following is code for my logic:

```
#define kAggressiveSpeedIncrementFactor 8.0f // if 8 km/h speed was increased in last second
#define kAggressiveAngleIncrementFactor 30.0f // 30 degree turn angle
#define kAggressiveTurnIncrementFactor 5.0f . // while turn the increasing speed factor in last second 

SOMotionDetector *motionDetector = [SOMotionDetector sharedInstance];
    motionDetector.locationChangedBlock = ^(CLLocation *location) {
        if (motionDetector.motionType == MotionTypeAutomotive) {

            SOLocationManager *locationManager = [SOLocationManager sharedInstance];
            float currSpeed = motionDetector.currentSpeed * 3.6f;
            float lastSpeed = motionDetector.lastSpeed * 3.6f;
            float currAngle = locationManager.currAngle;
            float lastAngle = locationManager.lastAngle;
            self.speedDiff = currSpeed-lastSpeed;
            self.angleDiff = currAngle-lastAngle;

            if (fabs(self.speedDiff)>kAggressiveSpeedIncrementFactor && fabs(self.angleDiff)<kAggressiveAngleIncrementFactor) {
                NSString *msg = @"Aggressive Speed";
                if (self.speedDiff < 0)
                    msg = @"Aggressive Break";
                NSLog(@"%@", msg);
            }

            if (fabs(self.angleDiff)>kAggressiveAngleIncrementFactor && currSpeed>kAggressiveTurnIncrementFactor) {
                NSLog(@"aggressive turn");
            }
        }
    };
```

I have created `currentSpeed` and `lastSpeed` in `SOMotionDetector` class (for my speed difference) and `currAngle` and `lastAngle` in `SOLocationManager`. Please have a look at code,

Aggressive Speed some times work perfect
My question is:

1. Is this right approach what I am doing?
2. For detecting aggressive turn with the angle some times this happens that if
   my vehicle is going 50 degrees angle (calculated with current and last lat, longs) on a strait road, some times the GPS detect location right or left side of road that give a big difference to the angle (like the path becomes a zig zag). any suggestion for this?

Comment: I guess it's too complicated task to solve with simple `if` checks with constants. I would propose overall approach how to deal with such kind of things: first, gather different logs of aggressive and calm driving, after that build your algorithm, iteratively testing each time if it recognizes driving style correctly. Also extract configurable params, like speed threshold, but more local and precise.

Comment: In other words. Use ML.